# Splitting a bilingual text into two parts using Python

Tags: python, split

input text: "gut, wird gemacht right, will do (inf)"
output text: gut, wird gemacht
right , will do (inf)
input text: gut, mache ich right, will do (inf) or I’ll do that
output text: gut , mache ich
right, will will do (inf) or I’ll do that
input text: "wie mans macht, ists verkehrt whatever you do is wrong"
output text: wie mans macht, ists verkehrt
whatever you do is wrong

Comment: Better you reformat your question before downvoters arrive here

Comment: No one will write code for you here. [ask]

Comment: There is no unambiguous way to tell when one language ends and the other starts. Therefore this is impossible to resolve

Comment: if this is your input (I don't understand it) ditch it and use a different format, the person that created your input should be banned from programming/typing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First off, please try to solve the problem yourself first. As @Julien points out, no one will write code for you.

To answer your question, you need to find an alghoritm that can detect which language a text is written in, and specify how certain it is (eg, [counting letter frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) has a surprisingly good hit rate, or you might want to use a database and compare words to that).

The next step is to choose an algorithm to find the most likely split. You could for instance evaluate each word individually, or try splitting the text in a couple locations to find what position is best.

Once you have that set up it's just a matter of trying different things until you get the accuracy you need.